# create file using grep values

Tags: linux, bash, grep, centos

I want to use the values I highlighted with `grep` from a file to be extracted and create a new file.

I have done the following:

```
grep -r "Bob-age[0-9]*\|Mark-age[0-9]*" > personInfo.txt
```

But I get the following  error:

```
grep: input file 'personInfo.txt' is also the output
```

How can I resolve this?

If have multiple line of the file, would I have to use a loop to go through every line to get it in the file?

Comment: You could write the output in the parent directory: `> ../personInfo.txt`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
grep -r "Bob-age[0-9]*\|Mark-age[0-9]*" . > personInfo.txt
```

That is adding a dot as the target of `grep`

or more concise:

```
grep -r "\(Bob\|Mark\)-age[0-9]*" . > personInfo.txt
```

Comment: The parentheses also need to be escaped for standard regular expressions, e.g. `\(Bob\|Mark\)`.